# Error "cannot set property gridDim of undefined" in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Getting error "cannot set property gridDim of undefined" while using ng-grid in angular js. i have already declared vm.gridOptions = { data: 'vm.course_view'};.plz help me

```
<section class="mainbar">
<section class="matter">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" ng-controller="Course_view">
         <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="widget wblue">
                <div vis-widget-header title="{{vm.title}}"></div>
                <div class="widget-content user">
                   <!--  <table data-toggle="table" data-height="150" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Lesson</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="c in vm.course_view"
                            >
                            <td>{{c.firstName}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table> -->
                    <div class="gridStyle"  ng-grid="course_view"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-foot">
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is Code for controller

```
 (function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.course_view')
        .controller('Course_view', Course_view);

    /* @ngInject */
    function Course_view($state, dataservice, logger) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.course_view = [];
        vm.title = 'Course_view';
        vm.gridOptions = { data: 'vm.course_view', columnDefs: [
                        {field:'firstName', displayName:'firstName'}
                         ]};

        activate();

        function activate() {
            return getCourse_View().then(function() {
                logger.info('Activated course_view View');
            });
        }

        function getCourse_View() {
            return dataservice.getCourse_View().then(function(data) {
                vm.course_view = data;
                debugger;
                return vm.course_view;
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Pleas, provide us more code. Or it would ever better, if you create JSFiddle for us.

Comment: Where your code? I see only one code row and it doesn't enough.

Comment: i have added code. please help.

Answer (score 3):

Please, try to change the following code:

1. `<div class="row" ng-controller="Course_view">`

on

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="Course_view as courseCtrl">
```

and

2. `<div class="gridStyle"  ng-grid="course_view"></div>`

on

```
<div class="gridStyle"  ng-grid="courseCtrl.course_view"></div>
```

And please, give me feedback about your success/fail in comments.

**UPDATE:**

I've created [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shepard_one/HB7LU/10297/) for you with working example.

I'm a little bit simplified example, but it should work.

```
<div ng-controller="CourseViewCtrl as ctrl">
  <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="ctrl.gridOptions"></div>
</div>

(function() { 
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngGrid']);

myApp.controller('CourseViewCtrl', CourseViewCtrl);

function CourseViewCtrl($http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.course_view = [];
    vm.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'ctrl.course_view'
    };

    activate();

    function activate() {
        return $http.get("/data").success(function(data) {
            vm.course_view = data;
        });
    };
}
})();
```

I want to note on main differences between your code:

Grid options in the controller:

```
vm.course_view = [];
vm.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'ctrl.course_view'
};
```

Grid on the view:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="ctrl.gridOptions"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks  Artyom.Now,i am not getting that error and getting layout of grid but not getting data from json.

Comment: @ranjitchoudhary, I've updated my answer and have created JSFiddle example for you. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Artyom Pranovich